# how to detect if a file operation is currently done on a file on linux

Tags: linux

How can i detect if a file is open and a file operation is being done on it by another process on linux by using c or c++? I know lsof lists all open files but i dont how it gets that information.

Thx

Comment: One question that comes into mind for me is, why you need this information. Depending on what you are trying to achieve, there are many other ways to get the same behavior, without actually handling any complicated syscalls.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure `lsof` is actually working like this, but a way to implement it could be this:

- get your process' open files by looknig to `/proc/$PID/fd/` files.
- look to any any other process' `/proc/$PID/fd/` in order to see who is reading your same files.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you look at the lsof source code? It's probably a bit intimidating, but I'm sure you can isolate the two or three interesting syscalls that give it all the relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

`lsof` iterates over all `/proc/*/fd/*` this can be seen if you do `strace` of the `lsof` command.